# How to create Random Password Generator using PHP?

Tags: php, random, passwords

This can generate random password.

```
<?php
function randomPassword() {
    $alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    $pass = array();
    $alphaLength = strlen($alphabet) - 1;
    for ($i = 0; $i < 26; $i++) {
        $n = rand(0, $alphaLength);
        $pass[] = $alphabet[$n];
    }
    return implode($pass);
}

echo randomPassword();
?>
```

But I want to save this password in `passwords.txt` file. And next time when create a new password, it will check this password is in that `passwords.txt` or not. And than echo.
If the password is already have, then go to the `else` condition and do it again.
How can I write this code?

Comment: You should note that `rand` is not secure enough to generate random passwords.  A better choice is `random_bytes` (in combination with `bin2hex`) or `random_int`, rather than `rand`.

Comment: Okk but my question was- how I can save them in password.txt file

Answer (score 1):

1. You want to use [`random_int()`](https://secure.php.net/random_int), not `rand()`.
2. There's a function called `file_put_contents()` that lets you write to a file. It even has an append mode.

For example:

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

function randomPassword(int $passwordLength = 26): string {
   $alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
   $pass = array();
    $alphaLength = strlen($alphabet) - 1;
    for ($i = 0; $i < $passwordLength; $i++) {
        $n = random_int(0, $alphaLength);
        $pass[] = $alphabet[$n];
    }
    return implode($pass);
}

$random = randomPassword();
file_put_contents(
    'passwords.txt',
    $random . "\n",
    FILE_APPEND
);
```